# What kind of frequency distribution is this?

Tags: distributions, frequency, distribution-identification

I have a discrete frequency distribution, that looks like this

[image: Frequency Distribution]

I am trying to find what type of distribution is it?

I looked at many models but it does not seem to comply with any.

I have 345 samples, each has a frequency. The top 20 frequencies sum is greater than the sum of the remaining 325.

**Update:**
Here is log-log plot

[image: Log-Log]

**Preto Chart**
[image: Preto]

**Data Sample**

`Rank    Frequency
1   11283380
2   10746051
3   9880160
4   7088819
5   6083811
6   5880305
7   5162758
8   5112340
9   4790522
10  4757319
11  4704226
12  4656856
13  4602855
14  4443199
15  3920582
16  3873183
17  3701584
18  3616144
19  3595352
20  3455586
21  3454769
22  3447600
23  3176357
24  2953578
25  2685691
26  2538326
27  2517904
28  2361178
29  2321718
30  2298187
31  2107593
32  2099459
33  2067878
34  2065825
35  2038860
36  2019911
37  1891243
38  1840260
39  1817637
40  1758235
41  1657344
42  1651883
43  1449834
44  1425727
45  1421574
46  1419489
47  1393750
48  1365944
49  1333684
50  1313764
51  1116110
52  1018205
53  933583
54  912332
55  904322
56  894303
57  892826
58  859628
59  847616
60  821070
61  811475
62  795705
63  782508
64  753768
65  746363
66  730726
67  712801
68  712707
69  705775
70  685044
71  680739
72  674921
73  648874
74  618832
75  595568
76  576773
77  503718
78  476542
79  461991
80  420085
81  418143
82  406194
83  399628
84  389467
85  371231
86  360972
87  355256
88  333312
89  329501
90  305836
91  304731
92  302782
93  293852
94  286274
95  283938
96  280961
97  279916
98  274902
99  274189
100 268081
101 260194
102 257674
103 256995
104 247407
105 237400
106 229708
107 226061
108 219854
109 218018
110 216291
111 216273
112 211697
113 206972
114 204153
115 195442
116 187550
117 184599
118 170596
119 165042
120 159314
121 151599
122 149400
123 149027
124 148454
125 147450
126 140889
127 138447
128 135733
129 132508
130 132454
131 131411
132 129300
133 128163
134 125816
135 125192
136 121761
137 121145
138 120907
139 119436
140 118433
141 117280
142 116796
143 111973
144 111952
145 108356
146 104955
147 103942
148 103926
149 102907
150 102593
151 102417
152 101877
153 101791
154 100472
155 100288
156 100113
157 99886
158 97052
159 92872
160 92184
161 89339
162 89162
163 88933
164 87373
165 84388
166 83532
167 82868
168 82654
169 81812
170 75932
171 71633
172 70269
173 67750
174 67559
175 66874
176 66612
177 65156
178 59972
179 58490
180 57894
181 56471
182 51145
183 50960
184 49638
185 49298
186 48752
187 48623
188 48569
189 48539
190 48476
191 47581
192 46281
193 45200
194 43946
195 43168
196 42729
197 42703
198 41507
199 41496
200 38928
201 38680
202 36862
203 36491
204 36234
205 35958
206 34705
207 34688
208 34061
209 33734
210 33018
211 32867
212 32700
213 32654
214 32342
215 31930
216 31621
217 31415
218 31403
219 30307
220 29358
221 29304
222 29049
223 27409
224 27165
225 26645
226 26499
227 26301
228 26184
229 25632
230 24927
231 24889
232 24826
233 24601
234 24439
235 24177
236 23539
237 23144
238 22564
239 22322
240 22267
241 21299
242 20884
243 20600
244 20439
245 19964
246 19680
247 18150
248 17424
249 17321
250 16927
251 16881
252 16442
253 15598
254 15520
255 15335
256 15177
257 14933
258 14303
259 13886
260 13870
261 13770
262 13462
263 13437
264 13233
265 13231
266 13206
267 13170
268 12991
269 12597
270 12583
271 12501
272 12438
273 11830
274 11757
275 11507
276 10953
277 10796
278 10792
279 10687
280 10251
281 9653
282 9538
283 8614
284 8232
285 8008
286 7916
287 7192
288 6956
289 6583
290 6469
291 6308
292 5691
293 5439
294 5251
295 4724
296 4208
297 3760
298 3692
299 3601
300 3555
301 3359
302 3332
303 3317
304 3267
305 3213
306 3188
307 3171
308 3075
309 2506
310 2097
311 2026
312 1756
313 1495
314 1491
315 1476
316 1283
317 1281
318 1165
319 1108
320 1032
321 970
322 821
323 796
324 780
325 729
326 616
327 549
328 538
329 536
330 535
331 533
332 375
333 250
334 176
335 14
336 7
337 5
338 4
339 3
340 3
341 2
342 2
343 1
344 1
345 1`

Comment: It looks like a rank-size distribution.

Comment: Actually rank-size must show a linear graph when a log-log plot is plotted This one shows a curved line concaved to the origin.

Comment: @AhmadHajjar Hi and welcome. 1) Please do post your log-log plot. 2) Please do post your [Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) fit.

Comment: Hi @Jim, Thank you for commenting ...  I updated the question :)

Comment: Hi @Jim I also added preto

Comment: Could you perhaps post a (tiny) random sample of your data, say 100 to 200 observations... then we can get our hands dirty... In any case, the Pareto fit does *not* look right in its current form ;D

Comment: @Jim I am not an expert :( however I posted a data sample for your kind reference :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this not just a Gamma distribution with a small `k`?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

Comment: I thought so but shouldn't the variable be continuous ?

Comment: thank you very much for bringing it up :D because I looked for analogue of gamma distribution for discrete variables, and found what I was looking for "Negative binomial distribution"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) to me. If you have the data used to create the plots you provided, you can try some [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) and see for yourself. In short, you want to find the [goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) for your observed data and the suspected distribution.

Comment: I dont think it is zeta distribution, if you look at the log-log plot I provided it shows a curve .. it does not show a linear relationship

Comment: @AhmadHajjar Thanks, it certainly looks like belonging to the power-law family. If you dump your data in an simple excel sheet it's not too hard to do the curve fitting - in case you want to be more confident.